# Why does importing subprocess change my output?

Tags: python, python-import, python-2.5

I noticed the following using Python 2.5.2 (does not occur using 2.7):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   print line,
```

Output:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | python test.py
$ one
$ two
$ three
```

as expected. However, if I import `subprocess` to the this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

for line in sys.stdin:
   print line,
```

Output:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | python test.py
$ two
$ three
```

What happened to the first line of output?

**Update:**

I think I may have discovered the root of the problem. I had a file named `time.py` in my `cwd`. A `time.pyc` is being created every time I run the script with `subprocess` imported, suggesting that `./time.py` is also being imported. The script runs normally if I delete the `.pyc` and `time.py` files; however, there is still the question of why a `subprocess` import would cause `./time.py` to be imported as well?

I have narrowed it down even further to the exact line in `time.py` that causes the strange behaviour. I have stripped down the working dir and file content to just that which affects the output:

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

for line in sys.stdin:
   print line,
```

**time.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   hour = re.search(r'\b([0-9]{2}):', line).group(1)
```

Running `test.py` with any kind of input results in the first line of output being omitted and `time.pyc` being created.

Comment: I can not confirm it on 2.4.3: "echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | python test.py" results in "-e one
two
three" for the last one example.

Comment: @tb-: You must use the bash shell. echo is a builtin, and tcsh (for example) does not support the -e flag.

Comment: hm, I can't actually confirm this at all: python2.5.6 on Ubuntu

Comment: @sharth with bash, the result is the same (without the -e)

Comment: @SilentGhost: I'm getting these results with 2.5.2 on Debian 5.0.6. Python 2.6.6 and 2.7.1 on the same machine behave as expected.

Comment: i have tried it with python2.6 and 2.7 and i get all the lines outputted correctly as you'd expect. it's not useful i know, but maybe there's something else you're missing

Comment: cannot confirm on python2.4.4 either

Comment: Does your `time.py` file do any input when run? If so, it's probably eating your "one" line. It's generally a bad idea to name your own modules with the same name as something in the standard library for this reason! Packages can help a bit.

Comment: @Blckknght: Well, `time.py` doesn't run; it's not a valid script as it is.

Comment: @user1227038: subprocess needs time in order to be able to `wait`. Anyway. This honestly is not the question that deserves time spent on it or upvotes it received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your local time.py will be imported instead of the global time module. You might want to rename it, or at least start checking if it was run as a script or imported as a module.

This will prove it for you if you want to test it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

# Test that script was run directly
if __name__=='__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
       hour = re.search(r'\b([0-9]{2}):', line).group(1)
else:
    print 'Imported local time.py instead of global time module!'
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score -2):

`print line,` before 2.7 did not put out a newline so it overwrote the first line. Lose the comma and the result will be the same.

Comment: why is line `two\n` was not overwritten? Besides, `import subprocess` shouldn't have affected it.

Comment: The behavior of the trailing comma was not changed in 2.7

Comment: The purpose of the trailing comma in `print` is to omit the newline, http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt "A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma"